# Visual Studio 2008, detecting mem leaks, the symbol '__FILE__' is not defined

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008, winapi

I am trying to identify memleaks in my c++ program. I use  Visual Studio 2008.

I have found a few tutorials dealing with identifying memleaks while using new, not malloc, for memory allocation and this is what i have defined on top of my main:

```
#define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS 

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#define DEBUG_NEW new(_NORMAL_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__)
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif
```

unfortunately I get tons of errors, which you can see here: http://pastebin.com/9ax90VTg

But I think I have found the problem: there is neighter `__FILE__` nor `__LINE__` defined. When I click "RMB->go to definition" OR "RMB->go to declaration" on `__FILE__`  or `__LINE__`  I get:

```
the symbol '__FILE__' is not defined
```

and

```
the symbol '__LINE__  ' is not defined
```

respectively.

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbols `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` should always be defined, by the compiler.  If they aren't, you must be using some special options to inhibit them.

On the other hand, the code you've posted cannot be used with the standard library, and so should be avoided.  It is *not* a good solution for finding memory leaks.

EDIT: On rereading your posting: you seem to be counting on the debugger to show you the definitions; it can't, because they are generated automatically by the compiler, changing during compilation.  On the other hand, the errors you are seeing are very compatible with the fact that your macro redefines a keyword, in a way that breaks the standard library code.

Comment: What is good solution then? I need to know exact line or at least method which causes leak.

Comment: @user1331072 The best solution is some sort of external tool, like valgrind.  Alternatively, you can write a replacement for the global `operator new` and `operator delete` (or even, in practice at least, for `malloc` and `free`).  Getting a stack walkback will require platform dependent code, but is generally not too difficult.  Interpreting it is more complex: my versions of `operator new`/`delete` simply output the return addresses in hex, and I exploit these manually, looking them up in a map of the process.

Answer (score 0):

You're barking up the wrong tree. `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` are handled by the preprocessor. They're not supposed to be defined. You didn't show us the actual code that generates those errors, so I'm not sure how we can help you with it.